# Is there a word for a system that requires interaction from two persons before an event happens

Tags: nouns

For example, when administering lethal injections, there are usually two buttons (each *on its own* harmless) that both need to be pressed by a person before it is administered.

Is there a name for such a system? I'm talking about a system that requires two people to interact to trigger the event, not a system that absolves one of them of guilt.

Comment: How can 'one be harmless' if it needs to be pressed? / The safety protocol is known, prosaically enough, as the "two man rule".

Comment: You might want to think about [Two-Factor Authentication](http://uk.pcmag.com/password-managers-products/9427/guide/two-factor-authentication-who-has-it-and-how-to-set-it-up) if you want something more generic (you still need two different "authorisations", but probably not two different *people* to deliver them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These systems use a [**two-man rule**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-man_rule):

> The two-man rule is a control mechanism designed to achieve a high level of security for especially critical material or operations. Under this rule all access and actions requires the presence of two authorized people at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Nuclear missles use something called **Permissive Action Link (PAL)**, think is more than just two buttons pressed though. Seems like needs a code typed in also. At least that's what get from watching Doctor Strangelove